# Creating Dynamics 365 entity record using WebAPI only

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I have connected to my CRM using C# and Azure. My requirement is that I need to create entity records using **WebAPI only**. In earlier versions, I had used IOrganization service and it worked fine. Now, I need to switch over to WebAPI.
I was able to read records using the webapi but can't figure out how to create the records.
I tried searching the web but couldn't find any relevant articles/tutorials.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way if you ever want to build WebAPI calls for JavaScript,  Jason Lattimer's [CRMRestBuilder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder) tool is indispensable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/web-api-basic-operations-sample-csharp#code-listing) is what you are looking for. As you already mentioned that you were able to read records using web api, you can use below snippet to create a new contact record using web api in C#.

```
JObject contact1 = new JObject();   
contact1.Add("firstname", "Peter");  
contact1.Add("lastname", "Cambel");  

HttpRequestMessage createRequest1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, https://xyz.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/contacts");  
createRequest1.Content = new StringContent(contact1.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");  

HttpResponseMessage createResponse1 = await httpClient.SendAsync(createRequest1);  

if (createResponse1.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)  //204  
{  
    Console.WriteLine("Contact '{0} {1}' created.", contact1.GetValue("firstname"), contact1.GetValue("lastname"));  
    contact1Uri = createResponse1.Headers.GetValues("OData-EntityId").FirstOrDefault();  
    entityUris.Add(contact1Uri);  
    Console.WriteLine("Contact URI: {0}", contact1Uri);  
}  
else  
{  
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to create contact for reason: {0}", createResponse1.ReasonPhrase);  
    throw new CrmHttpResponseException(createResponse1.Content);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example creates a new account entity. The response OData-EntityId header contains the Uri of the created entity

```
POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Accept: application/json

{
"name": "Sample Account",
"creditonhold": false,
"address1_latitude": 47.639583,
"description": "This is the description of the sample account",
"revenue": 5000000,
"accountcategorycode": 1
}
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
 OData-Version: 4.0
 OData-EntityId: [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts(7eb682f1-ca75-e511-80d4- 
 00155d2a68d1)
```

To create a new entity you must identify the valid property names and types.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but where do I execute this? I need to use C# to create the entities. Sorry, I am a beginner at this.

Comment: this is c# code dear you just creat above json file and send request throw api